# eclipse 2019 03 and TFS

Tags: eclipse, tfs, azure-devops

I installed the latest version of eclipse and I am trying to install the TFS plugin but I have the following error:

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in
>   "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui" was Unable to instantiate class
>   "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.views.TeamExplorerView".

Comment: Help me please. I m je suis bloqué

Comment: Help me please. I am blocked and it is very urgent